# What does (function() {}) do?

Tags: javascript, function

What does the following () do? It seems prints out the content inside ().

```
(function() {
    console.log("test");
});
```

This is how ExtJS 4 defines the version:

```
(function() {

// Current core version
var version = '4.1.1', Version;
    Ext.Version = Version = Ext.extend(Object, {
    ...
});
```

Comment: There is no following () here... but if there was, it's to execute the anonymous function preceding it.

Comment: It won't do much, as it is not called.

Comment: You probably wanted this: (function() {
console.log("test");
})();

Comment: Some context, please. Do you know what `console.log` is?

Comment: Could you provide some context? Wouldn't this happen to be part of an assignment or string concatenation?

Comment: Notice that your code specifying how Ext-JS defines the Ext.Version is not accurate (it would do nothing if it were the way you showed), see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does nothing. It's a function expression surrounded in parenthesis. Without them, you will get an error.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to have to assume you incorrectly copied code.

<sub>This does nothing</sub>

```
(function() {
console.log("test");
});
```

<sub>This writes "test" to the console</sub>

```
(function() {
console.log("test");
}());
```

The real question it seems like you're asking is, *why*.

`function () {...}` defines a new anonymous function.

`function () {...}()` calls the anonymous function

`(function () {...}());` parens are used to force the execution of the function. Without an operator of some sort, the JS interpreter would throw a SyntaxError.

The reason someone would put an [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) inline in some code is to introduce a new variable scope. In JavaScript, blocks don't have scope, which can lead to some very confusing errors for new developers who are not aware of the issue.

Additionally, using a function as a wrapper prevents `var` and `function` declarations from polluting the global namespace, and instead are privately held within the IIFE. This is *A Good Thing™*.

---

Given the additional information J Any posted:

<sub>"This is how ExtJS 4 defines the version"</sub>

```
(function() {

// Current core version
var version = '4.1.1', Version;
    Ext.Version = Version = Ext.extend(Object, {
    ...
});
```

The code posted is incomplete. Braces and parens were not matched correctly.

The end `});` belongs to `Ext.extend(Object, {` ***not*** `(function () {`.

Comment: +1 OP did paste the incorrect code, the matching close bracket for the function is `}());`

Comment: @zzzzBov: +1. Just for clarification, am I right in thinking that only the third example (the anonymous function wrapped in parens) is an example of an _immediately invoked function expression_? If the purpose of the parens is to create a private scope for the anonymous function, would you explain how this is different to the second example (the anon function without parens). Presumably since this is anonymous also, this doesn't modify the global namespace either?

Comment: @halfer, after re-reading my answer, I can see how it would lead to confusion. JavaScript has functional scope, not block scope. The function is what provides the new scope, not the wrapping parens. The point of the parentheses is to allow the code to be syntactically valid, easily readable, and executable. Some programmers will instead use other operators such as `!` to force the JS interpreter to execute the function, as in `!function(){}()`. In my experience `(function(){...}());` is the most common.

Comment: In my experience, `(function(){})()` is the most common, this was actually the first time I saw this variant

Answer (score 7):

It does nothing, that code can never get called since the anonymous function or any other symbols in it are not exposed.

If you add `()` to the end, that is a self calling anonymous function, which is usually used to create some local variables that aren't accessible to the rest of the code

```
(function() {
console.log("test");
})();
```

The reason the code that Ext-JS does make sense is because they are making some code inside the anonymous function available to the outside by calling

```
Ext.Version = Version = Ext.extend(Object, ...
```

And you have a typo in your sample Ext-JS Code. Their code is actually the following

```
(function() {
    // Current core version
    var version = '4.1.1', Version;
    // Exposes our local Version into the global Ext.Version object
    Ext.Version = Version = Ext.extend(Object, {
    //... More code
    });   
}()) // See the brackets after the function? That runs the code above immediately
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that alone would do nothing. It defines an anonymous function, which would never be able to be referenced or called later.

However, this:

```
(function() {
console.log("test");
})();
```

would define an anonymous function *and call it*, printing "test" to the console. The first bit is the same as what you have in the question, and the last `()` calls the function.